# Why is this character, in a string in a PHP array, invisible or becoming white space?

Tags: php

I've been away from PHP for several years, so maybe I've forgotten something basic.

If I do:

```
print_($output_array);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
[0] => HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
[1] => Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
[2] => Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2022 19:07:36 GMT
[3] => Connection: close
[4] => X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.29-to-be-removed-in-future-macOS
[5] => Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[6] => 
[7] => You are only allowed to make one request every 15 seconds.
)
```

But if I do:

```
echo $meta[0];
```

In the terminal, I get:

```
 TTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
```

There is an empty white space at the beginning, where I expect an "H".

Same problem here:

```
echo "Content type is: \n";
echo $meta[5] . " \n";
```

I get:

```
  ontent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

There is a blank white space at the beginning of the line, where I expect a "C".

Why is this?

If I do this:

```
if ($meta[5] == 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "bad";
}
```

I get `bad`.

Comment: There's a carriage return followed by space at the end of each string. So it's going back to the beginning of the line and the space is overwriting the first character.

Comment: I strongly recommend you always use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()`. It tells you the length of each string, and this is useful for detecting invisible characters since the length will be longer than the characters you see.

Comment: Interesting. So the newline "\n" messes things up? What should I do instead?

Comment: Not newline `\n`, carriage return `\r`. Newline goes to the next line, carriage return goes to the beginning of the same line.

Comment: Okay. So I just strip out the "\r"?

Comment: The original string probably had `\r\n` as the line breaks. Then you used `explode("\n", $string)`, which left the `\r` in the strings. Use `explode("\r\n", $string)` instead.

Comment: The short long version is that when computers output to what were essentially typewriters `\n` advanced the print feed by one line, and `\r` returned the print head carriage to the beginning of the line. Some OSes/programs/protocols have evolved to using simply `\n` for both, but a rogue `\r` can still cause fun issues.